# Wrong element selection behaviour

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm wondering why in the example of two rectangles provided below, the yellow one shows selection borders properly by clicking on that element, but RED one is not? It does select an element by clicking in the empty top-left area of the canvas.
How to fix that using this scenario?

http://jsfiddle.net/201y9s3m/5/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');

const red = new fabric.Rect({
    x: 100, 
    y: 50,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

const yellow = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100, 
    top: 150,
    fill: 'yellow',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
canvas.add(red);
canvas.add(yellow);
canvas.renderAll();

red.setPositionByOrigin({x:100, y:50}, 'left', 'top');
canvas.renderAll();

console.log('Red Left should be 100 but gets ', red.getLeft());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [this issue was raised a few years back](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1717).

One solution is to call `setCoords()` after `setPositionByOrigin()`, like this:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');

const red = new fabric.Rect({
    x: 100, 
    y: 50,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

const yellow = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100, 
    top: 150,
    fill: 'yellow',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
canvas.add(red);
canvas.add(yellow);
canvas.renderAll();

red.setPositionByOrigin({x:100, y:50}, 'left', 'top');
red.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();

console.log('Red Left should be 100 but gets ', red.getLeft());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you Brett. Really helped me.